# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, prove $|syl_pH| \leq |syl_pG|$ $\forall p.$

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, prove $|syl_pH| \leq |syl_pG|$ $\forall p.$

Let $P \in syl_pG$. Then we know that:

$|syl_pG|=[G:N_G(P)] \cong 1$ mod p

$|syl_pH|=[H:N_H(P)] \cong 1$ mod p

Anyone have some insight into this problem for me?

$syl_pG$ is the set of sylow-p subgroups in $G$

Comment: Think about your definition of $syl_p H$ --- what exactly is that thing? Also: any subgroup of $H$ is also a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Theorem 6.6 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/sylowapp.pdf.

Comment: It would improve the Question to provide a definition of $syl_pG$.  Indeed the word Sylow does not appear in the post currently, and while the notation is suggestive, a concrete definition is important (perhaps more than half the battle, in this case).

Comment: @JohnHughes yes but a Sylow-p subgroup in $H$ can be different than a Sylow-p subgroup of $G$ , like if $p^i$ is the highest factor of $p$ in the prime factorization of $|G|$ maybe $p^{i-1}$ is the highest factor of $p$ in the prime factorization of $|H|$

Comment: $syl_pG$ is the set of sylow-p subgroups in $G$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B$ be two $p$-Sylow subgroups of $H$ there exists Sylow $p$-subgroups $A',B'$ of $G$ such that $A'\cap H=A, B'\cap H=B$. Suppose that $A'=B'$ this implies that $A,B\subset A'$ and the $C$ subgroup generated by $A,B$ is a $p$-group, this implies that $C=A=B$ since $A,B$ are maximal $p$-subgroups.